# How to browse data on a RAID disk

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I've 2 disks in RAID1 and want to access it's files.
In the Disks app I see both of them:

1. /dev/sdc
2. /dev/sdd

In the terminal when I try to enter these I get an error saying "Not a directory".
I can't find any of the drives in the Files app. I'm using Ubuntu 20 live CD.

What should I do? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see where they are mounted? Please show output of `ls /mnt`

Comment: Nothing is returned for `ls /mnt`. I thought if they show up in /dev they are mounted, sorry. How can I mount disks in raid?

Comment: Then they are not mounted at least. I'm not an expert on hardware raid, though. But you should rephrase your question, stating that the disks are in fact NOT mounted.

Comment: /dev/sdX are the "system" reference for the block devices, and not a usable directory per se.

Comment: Hmm, maybe they are mounted under `/media` - can you try `ls /media`

Comment: Try and search for mdadm raid, and see if that helps - I'm just assuming it's an mdadm based raid.

Comment: `ls /media` returns a line: cdrom.

Comment: Ok then it's not mounted there either.

Comment: I also tried to `sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt` but I get an error saying "unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'"

Answer (score 0):

You said you use Ubuntu 20 live CD and that the two drives are in Raid 1.
What software are you using for the Raid: mdraid, zfs? Or you are using a RAID hardware controller or your motherboard provides it?.
With what OS you created the RAID? Was this working with Ubuntu previously or you created in a Windows system and booting with Ubuntu live you want to access the Data?.

To know what is mounted type:

```
mount
```

This will list the mounted filesystems.
However as you're booting from a live Ubuntu the system will not attempt to mount the local drives, even if it could, if you don't do manually.

Cheers

Comment: I believe my motherboard provides the RAID, before the BIOS post there is an option to configure it. Previously it was working on Windows, but now Windows wont boot with it although the system itself is on an other drive. After running`sudo dmraid -rE /dev/sdc` the drive showed up in file manager and I have access to the files.